# Python : How do I edit the property of the recently added modifier without using its name

Tags: python, modifiers

I have this Boolean operator which adds a Boolean to the active object and adds the second in order to the object property
but this wont more than once because the second modifier added wont be `dif`
it would be `dif.001`
How do i automate this name issue

```
class BoolOp(Operator):
    """Quick Booelan Operation"""
    bl_idname = "extorctools.boolop" 
    bl_label = "Bool Op"    
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
    def execute(self, context):
        target = bpy.context.active_object
        lis = bpy.context.selected_objects
        cutter = []
        for x in range(len(lis)):
            if len(lis) == 1:
                raise Exception("2 Objects must be selected")
            elif not lis[x] == target:
                cutter.append(lis[x])
                break
        try:
            target.modifiers.new(name = f"dif" , type = 'BOOLEAN')
            target.modifiers['dif'].object = cutter[0]
        except:
            pass
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

What i want to be able to do is to do something like this `target.modifiers[the.most.recent.modifier.of.type.BOOLEAN].object = cutter[0]`

Comment: `obj.modifiers.new(...)` returns the modifier. Use `new_mod = obj.modifiers.new(...)`

Comment: @Gorgious works like a charm
you can write that as an answer
btw i had a question
how do u get along these details
like this function returns what

Comment: you can find it in the api - reference of blender: https://docs.blender.org/api/latest/bpy.types.ObjectModifiers.html#bpy.types.ObjectModifiers

Comment: @SHikhaMittal Yup, it's not funny to study the API docs but the more you dive into it, the easier it will be to get things done in your scripts :)